# Displaying Android Screenshots

Tags: screenshots

I have a few screenshots of an application that I want to display on a website.

I remember there used to be a web site that had all the "frames" or "skins" of Android devices; you would upload your screenshot and it would embed them in the frame and you would get images like this:

[image: Prettified Screenshot]

I can't seem to be able to find the site or these "frames". Can anyone please point me to a direction where I can get these frames?

p.s. I can do photoshop myself if I can get these "frames" (or whatever they're called).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the [Device Art Generator](http://developer.android.com/distribute/promote/device-art.html).